# CSS3 - Animation Scale/Rotate on Hover

Tags: css, css-animations

I tried and wrote this code but it have a problem, first issue is text inside div will be fuzzy (fluffy)! and second scale animation not play softly, all i want is play animation softly, scale once then rotate infinite on hover.

```
@-webkit-keyframes socialspin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(2)rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(2) rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: scale(2) rotate(0deg);
    transform: scale(2) rotate(0deg);
  }

   to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotateY(90deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(2) rotateY(90deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(2) rotateY(90deg);
    -o-transform: scale(2) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: scale(2) rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
```

Here is **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLypmxa0/5/)** Demo

Comment: scale works a little fuzzy yeah

Comment: shouldn't the scale value be 1 in the `from` part of the animation?

Comment: I am very confused by the question. The text is blurred because you are using an animation, which is done to make the transition seem smoother.  What scale animation are you on about? There is only one in your question and it is constant: there won't be a transition.

Comment: sorry for my bad english (probably) , 1st issue: text inside the div is fuzzy,  any solution to fix this? 2st issue: scale run without any animation (softly). @jaunt transition not help to make it smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to have a smooth result is not to have a zoom in (scale=2) but a zoom out (scale=0.5), but of course in the opposite state.

And I don't believe that what you want can be achieved with a single animation. I have used 2 elements, and one handles the rotation and the other the scale

```css
#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

#container:hover {
  -webkit-animation: socialspin 5s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}


@-webkit-keyframes socialspin {
  from {    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  }
   to {    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);  }
}
@keyframes socialspin {
  from {    transform: rotate(0deg);  }
   to {    transform: rotateY(90deg);  }
}

#base {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: yellow;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transition: transform 5s;
    transform-origin: top left;
    font-size: 200%;
}

#container:hover #base {
    transform: scale(1);
 
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="base">
    
<br>
<br>
<br>    
HELLLLOOOO!!!
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/tLypmxa0/11/) is the example and the point is first to describe all features in the main div as defaults because animation uses main elements rules to calculate time etc.
and second point here you used 90 degrees to turn but a complete turning back can be done by 180 degrees which is the angle of a line
here is the code

--update--
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/tLypmxa0/13/) is the exxample you can see scale animates the problem was in your animation scaling started from 2 and ended by 2 so there was no animation for that
--update-- 
here we go if you run transition first and by the time while transition is running  make animation wait by delay time of animation it works fine you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tLypmxa0/17/)

```
 div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0);
            transform:scale(1) rotate(0);
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:50px;
    transition:-webkit-transform .5s linear;
    transition:transform .5s linear;
}

div:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(2) rotate(0);
            transform:scale(2) rotate(0);
  -webkit-animation: socialspin 5s linear .5s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: socialspin 5s linear .5s infinite alternate;
}


@-webkit-keyframes socialspin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotate(0deg);
    transform:scale(2)  rotate(0deg);
  }

   to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: scale(2) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: No my friend, i want to scale(2) on hover! not on default. in your fiddle still have problems. scale not works smoothly, text still is fuzzy.

Comment: about fuzzy text i dont think you can do something try to make animation faster by shortening the time and this issue might be slightly invisible

Comment: ok, i see your update, but still have a problem, as i tell in question, i want to run scale animation ONCE, then run rotate in infinite.

Comment: check the solution and please if it solves mark as solution @ITSolution

Answer (score 1):

<s>We cannot, as of yet, completely make the font clear. This is because you are using an animation. If there was no spinning, the text would not be fuzzy. However, we can try using several font smoothing properties to try and combat this. None of them are very good but they do improve legibility slightly.</s>

Regardless, here is the fix for the second part:

I found a hack. This will remove the blur during the rotation but not during the scaling up.

```css
.square {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:black;
  margin: 50px;
}
p {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
.square:hover {
  -webkit-animation: scale 1s linear 0s 1, spin 1s linear 1s infinite alternate;
}
.square:hover p{
 -webkit-animation: scaletext 1s linear 0s 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes scale {
  from {transform:  scale(1); }
  to{transform:  scale(2);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes scaletext {
  from {transform:  scale(1); }
  to{transform:  scale(1);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {transform:  rotateY(0deg) scale(2) ;}
  to {transform:  rotateY(90deg) scale(2);}
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <p>Some text</p>                        
</div>
```

(I removed the prefixes to condense the answer)